# Fence device for RHEL cluster node on vmware workstation

Tags: redhat, cluster, vmware-workstation, fencing

I have a host with Windows 7. I installed VMware Workstation where I have installed two virtual machines. Each virtual machine is a rhel 6.2 node running clustersuite.

Do you know which fence device I can use in order to configure the cluster?

Comment: What are you using to host the virtual machines...Hyper V? VMware?

Comment: Vmware Workstation, I edited the answer